# How to convert Date Time into String value?

Tags: asp.net

I try to Convert String into Date. I get the error such as Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'String'.

**Aspx code**

```
            p.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text);
```

Can you help me, How solve this error.

Comment: Check the type of p.Dob, and I bet you'll see that it is a string, and you are taking a string from a text box, converting it to a date, then trying to set a string property to that date.

Comment: No Sir, p.Dob's type is Date Time in my Property.cs till get the error.

Comment: Your question is the opposite of your code. Your code is converting a string to a date, while your question is about converting a date to a string. Which do you want to do?

Comment: I  want to convert string to Date.

Comment: Thank you i got the error...

Answer (score 0):

If "p.Dob" is string:

```
p.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```